# Print only the panel content

Tags: extjs4.1

I'm using `ExtJS` to show an barcode image. I wanna print that image using the print dialog after do click in a button.

I have a function like this:

```
function barcode_impr(pkIdGuess){

    var win = new Ext.Window({
        title: 'Barcode',
        layout: 'fit',
        autoScroll: true,
        y: 120,
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
        modal: true,
        closeAction: 'hide',
        items:
            [{
                xtype: 'panel',
                //height:'100px',
                docked: 'bottom',
                html: 'Here goes an image...',
                scrollable: true,
                renderTo: document.body,
                id: 'panel_print',
                tools: [{
                    type: 'print',
                    handler: function() {
                        window = Ext.getCmp('panel_print');
                        window.print();
                    }
                }]
            }]
    });
    win.show();
}
```

but that show all not only the panel content. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I have made a function `doPrint` with 2 parameters `pnlId` (the id of the panel in which your bar code image is placed) and `win` (the window reference)

We can use this function like below:-

```
doPrint('panel_print', win);
```

This function creates an `iframe` and print the content which we want and then it destroy the `iframe`.

> [Working example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2fp0)

**Code snippet:-**

```
function doPrint(pnlId, win) {
    var pnl = Ext.getCmp(pnlId);
    var iFrameId = "printerFrame";
    var printFrame = Ext.get(iFrameId);

    if (printFrame == null) {
        printFrame = Ext.create('Ext.Component', {
            id: iFrameId,
            autoEl: {
                tag: "iframe"
            }
        });
        printFrame.addCls('x-hidden');
        win.add(printFrame);
    }

    var cw = printFrame.el.dom.contentWindow;

    // get the contents of the panel and remove hardcoded overflow properties
    var markup = pnl.body.dom.innerHTML;

    while (markup.indexOf('overflow: auto;') >= 0) {
        markup = markup.replace('overflow: auto;', '');
    }

    var str = Ext.String.format('<html><head>{0}</head><body><img src="resources/images/gabar-logo.gif">{1}</body></html>', '', markup);

    // output to the iframe
    cw.document.open();
    cw.document.write(str);
    cw.document.close();

    // remove style attrib that has hardcoded height property
    // cw.document.getElementsByTagName('DIV')[0].removeAttribute('style');

    // print the iframe
    cw.print();
    // destroy the iframe
    Ext.fly(iFrameId).destroy();
};
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Quite nice idea and fiddle. Thanks.